# Issue in parallelising inner loop of a nested for in OpenMP

Tags: multithreading, loops, parallel-processing, nested, openmp

I need to parallelize the inner of a nested loop with OpenMP. They way I did it is not working fine. Each thread should iterate on each of the M points, but only iterate(in the second loop) on its own chunk of coordinates. So I want the first loop to go from  `0`  to  `M` , the second one from`my_first_coord`  to  `my_last_coord`. In the code I posted, the program is faster when launched with 4 threads than when with 8, so there's some issue. I know one way to do this is by "manually" dividing the coordinates, meaning that each thread gets its own  `num_of_coords / thread_count`(and considering the remainder), I did that with Pthread. I would prefer to make use of pragmas in OpenMP. I'm sure I'm missing something. Let me show you the code

```
#pragma omp parallel
... 
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) { //All iterate from i to M
#       pragma omp for nowait
        for (int coord = 0; coord < N; coord++) { //each works on its portion of coords

            centroids[points[i].cluster].accumulator.coordinates[coord] += points[i].coordinates[coord];
        }
    }
```

I put the Pthread version too, so that you don't misunderstand what I want to achieve, but with the use of pragmas

```
/*M is global, 
first_nn and last_nn are local*/
        for (long i = 0; i < M; i++)
            for(long coord = first_nn; coord <= last_nn; coord++) 
            centroids[points[i].cluster].accumulator.coordinates[coord] += points[i].coordinates[coord];
```

I hope that it is clear enough. Thank you

Edit:
I'm using gcc 12.2.0. By adding the `-O3` flag times have improved.
With larger inputs the difference is speedup between 4 and 8 threads is more significant.

Comment: What do you mean by not working fine? Incorrect result? Note that 1) parallelization has overheads, and in you case the workload is very small. 2) your code is memory bound, so, I am not surprised that it is not scaling well with number of threads.

Comment: 200K points, 10 coordinates, it's faster with 4 threads than with 8. In Pthreads with 8 is much faster than 4. Is it just because of the Omp overhead? Are the loop boundary variables computed at each of the M iterations, and this is what is making it slow?

Comment: What prevent you using `first_nn` and `last_nn` in OpenMP without the omp for?

Comment: Do you mean that M=200,000 and N=10?

Comment: Try what @JérômeRichard suggested. If it is much faster, then it is due to the overhead of `omp for`. ps: Why don't you parallelize the outer loop? Is there a dependency?

Comment: Okay thank you, so my code is syntactically correct, it's just an overhead problem. But could you please tell me, if possible, what is omp doing in the `omp for`? Is it just indices computation, or (I guess yes) something more complicated? Thank you all.

Comment: @PierU yes, M = 200'000, N = 10

Comment: @Laci There could be a race condition if for some `i != j` one have `points[i].cluster==points[j].cluster` (but I don't know if it can happen).

Comment: @MeLaRia so no wonder why it's slower... With an `omp for` with such a small number of iterations and such a low workload per iteration, the overheads dominate.

Comment: @PierU, it may happen, but threads are writing on different coordinates so there's no critical section.

Comment: @PierU okay, thank you. But is it just the time taken for computing the indexes at each iteration? What does this overhead consist of?

Comment: @MeLaRia Which compiler and compiler options do you use?

Comment: @Laci gcc -std=c11 -Wall -g -fopenmp

Comment: Which version of gcc? Please add all these infos to the question by editing it instead of commenting them.

Comment: Without optimization (`-O3`) g++ 12.2 calls `omp_get_num_threads` and `omp_get_thread_num` in each loop and indices are recalculated. Try using `-O3` flag and set your CPU properly (e.g. -mavx2). (This also helps vectorization)

Comment: Benchmarking a debug build is worthless.

Comment: With optimization turned on, I wouldn't be surprised if the serial version was faster, actually

Comment: @PierU it is not

Comment: Well, I've built a similar example based on your code and your sizes, and the serial version is faster than the `omp for` version... In the serial version the inner loop is vectorized, and on 10 elements it's difficult for openmp to perform better

Comment: The main problem is that a lot of information are missing. We really need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We also need informations like the specific target processor used to run this and the command lines to build and run the program. Tricky things like the memory alignment can drastically impact the performance of the target program (due to false sharing) and this is just one possible option amongst many others. Without that, we can only do wild guesses and ask a lot of questions which is inefficient.

Comment: @PierU Sorry it was a 100 N. Anyway I'm not going to ask questions this way anymore. Sorry. Thanks all for your help. The most important thing was that the code is syntactically correct, and you answered to that, and also the -Optimization flag is a good thing to know about.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment indicates that you are worried about speedup.

1. How many physical cores does your processor have? Try every thread count from 1 to that number.
2. Do not use hyperthreads
3. You may find a good speedup for low thread counts, but a leveling off effect: that is because you have a "streaming" operation, which is limited by bandwidth. Unless you have a very expensive processor, there is not enough bandwidth to keep all cores running fast.
4. You could try setting `OMP_PROC_BIND=true` which prevents the OS from migrating your threads. That can improve cache usage.
5. You have some sort of indirect addressing going on with the `i` variable so further memory effects related to the TLB may make your parallel code not scale optimally.

But start with point 3 and report.